# Databinding Exception Cannot format the value to the desired type hard to debug

Tags: .net, winforms, exception, data-binding, devexpress

We're using a lot of databinding in our winforms application and we've recently hit some hard to debug scenario's.

On calling ResumeBinding() on our BindingSource we receive an Exception:

> ex.Type FormatException
>       ex.Message Cannot format the value to the desired type:
>
> at System.Windows.Forms.Binding.FormatObject(Object value)
>       at System.Windows.Forms.Binding.PullData(Boolean reformat, Boolean force)
>       at System.Windows.Forms.BindingManagerBase.PullData(Boolean& success)
>       at System.Windows.Forms.CurrencyManager.CurrencyManager_PullData()
>       at System.Windows.Forms.CurrencyManager.EndCurrentEdit()
>       at System.Windows.Forms.CurrencyManager.ChangeRecordState(Int32 newPosition, Boolean validating, Boolean endCurrentEdit, Boolean firePositionChange, Boolean pullData)
>       at System.Windows.Forms.CurrencyManager.UpdateIsBinding(Boolean raiseItemChangedEvent)
>       at System.Windows.Forms.CurrencyManager.UpdateIsBinding()
>       at System.Windows.Forms.CurrencyManager.ResumeBinding()
>       at System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource.ResumeBinding()
>       at SomeProject.SomePanel.FlightData_DataReady() in C:\SomeDir\SomePanel.cs:line 94

We're using a simple object model with some Nullable properties. Not all of them have try catches around the setters/getters though

We're using DevExpress components, this particular exception started after changing a property into a Nullable property and adding a NullText property to the DevExpress textbox.

Can anyone shine a light on how to debug this situation?

---

After working on this problem a bit more I've noticed some particulars creating this problem.

One of the Nullable double properties was binded to a control that has a Single property. The databinding engine threw some First change exceptions about not being able to convert a Nullable double into a Single.

Debugging this and finding which control/property was to blame is still impossible to do, anyone got some clues how to do this?

Comment: how do you set the datasource of the grid, what kind of objects do you store in it, why kind of property would you make nullable when you bind it to a textbox (a textbox/string is already nullable)?

Comment: It would help if you posted some code: the class that contains the nullable properties and the form with databinding.

Comment: @Martin that should not really help me debug the code from an Exploration standpoint. I don't know which databinding control/code is the culprit and which properties are to blame.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try enabling formatting

```
this.myTextBox1.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("EditValue", this.bindingSource1, "MyProperty", true));
```

Notice the true-parameter

Setting this property to true also enables error-handling behavior and causes the BindingComplete event to be raised. The handler of this event can take the appropriate action, based on the success, error, or exceptions in the binding process, by examining the BindingCompleteState property of the BindingCompleteEventArgs parameter.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.binding.formattingenabled.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, but we've got a lot of databinding and I'm trying to decide which one needs the property set/what's going on exactly.

Comment: I don't have sufficent reputation to downvote this answer. You're missing the question. I have the same problem as the OP. I have a form with dozens of databound fields. Suddenly, I'm seeing this problem and I have no way to tell which field is failing. The question is how do you determine which field is failing. It's an awful error message. The exception's stack trace contains no useful context.

Comment: Downvote: isn't that a bit to harsh? Maybe you should have taken the time to read the MSDN-article. It includes a portion on error-handling which is possible due to the true-parameter.

Comment: @Dan - accidentally left my response to you as an answer. As it pertained to DevExpress controls at the time, the suggested answer did not help. The question is can you get anywhere with debugging this without potentially changing hundreds (or thousands) of lines of code. I found the answer to that to be no.

Comment: This worked for me, I did not have as many bindings so it wasn't much of a PITA. But regarding Visual Studio exception message it is actually completely useless. This is yet another magical solution to a very obscure issue.

Comment: Hello, this answer was the solution of my problem, too. But it would be nice if there would be an explanation. Why Does something like "btn.DataBindings.Add("Visible", aControl, "Visible", False)" fail, in different cultures. I know that Convert.ChangeType uses culture, but why does it fail with the two boolean types "Visible"? EDIT: the controls are DevExpress Controls.